# I cannot seem to get a seperate ID for each block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a school project, and I want to add and take fields away (they should clone each other but with different ID's). This is done in *javascript*.

Maybe i'm missing out on something or straight up doing something wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-primary'
  }).on('click', function(){
    $('.jumbotron').append(getExerciseBlock(i));
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
  $('.jumbotron').append(addOpdracht);
  for(var i = 0; i< 0; i++){
    $('.jumbotron').append(getExerciseBlock(i));
  }
})


function getAddBtn(target, i){
  var addBtn = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-primary'
  }).on('click', function(){
    $(target).append(getWordPartInput(i));
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
  console.log(target);
  return addBtn;
}

function getExerciseBlock(i){
  var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
    'id': i,
    'class': 'col-md-12'
  });
  $(eBlock).append(getAudioBtn(i), getWordInput(i), 
    getWordPartInput(i),getAddBtn(eBlock, i));
  return eBlock;
}


function getAddBtn(target, i){
  var addBtn = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-primary'
  }).on('click', function(){
    $(target).append(getWordPartInput(i));
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
  console.log(target);
  return addBtn;
}

function getAudioBtn(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var audioBtn = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-primary'
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>');
  return audioBtn;
}

function getWordInput(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'form-group form-control',
    'type': 'text',
    'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[]',
    'placeholder': 'Exercises'
  })
  return wInput;
}

function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'form-group form-control',
    'type': 'text',
    'value': cValue,
    'placeholder': 'Syllables'
  });
  return wpInput;
}
```

So, what the idea should be:

- I click on var `addOpdracht` and it adds a whole extra field (it's basically cloning), but I need the clone to get an ID.
- The first field starts with ID 0, but when I click to clone it gives the second field an ID of 0 as well.
- I want it to get ID = 1 so I can send it to a JSON file and later on
  pull it back based off its ID.

*So what is it that i'm either doing wrong or not seeing ? 
Please clarify this for me as well.*

SECOND EDIT: my HTML code below.
THRID EDIT: I found out that the i I set to 0 defines the ID, but if I were to set i = 0; i< 10; i++ it will give me 10 input blocks to start off with, but I want one block to start with and whenever I click on it to reproduce the block again, but I want that one to have an ID of +1. 
I'm sorry for all the EDITS. I am just trying to keep up to date on the stuff I have been trying.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
    <title>Exercise CMS</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/vendor/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/exercise_CMS.js"></script>

    <link rel="icon" href="http://dk.fcsprint2.nl/favicon.ico?v=2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/vendor/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/vendor/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/fonts.css">
   <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->
      <!-- <script src="cms.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2 id="exerciseTitle" class="col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-6">CMS</h2>
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
                                    <h2>
                                        <select class="languageSelector form-control required" id="languageSelector" ></select>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>      <!-- end of panel-heading -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="jumbotron" id="mainList">
                        <form class="container-fluid" method="POST">

                        </form>
                    </div> 
                </div>      <!-- end of panel-body -->          
            </div>      <!-- end panel-primary -->
        </div>      <!--end panel-group -->
    </div>  <!-- end of container-->
```

Comment: Problem come from your event listener 'click'. You don’t increment m 'i' that means it is always equals to 0 that why you get id=0 all the time just when you add new block set i++; to increment 'i'

Comment: but I already have the increment don't I?

Comment: I don't see where is your increment??

Comment: Also please provide your html to us

Comment: uhm.. yeah.. I don't really use HTML, but if u wanna see sure why not. ill edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chage your:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-primary'
  }).on('click', function(){
    $('.jumbotron').append(getExerciseBlock(i));
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
  $('.jumbotron').append(addOpdracht);
  for(var i = 0; i< 0; i++){
    $('.jumbotron').append(getExerciseBlock(i));
  }
})
```

with that and will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = 0;
    var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
       'class': 'btn btn-primary'
    }).on('click', function(){
        $('.jumbotron').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
        id++;
    }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');

    $('.jumbotron').append(addOpdracht);
})
```

And one tip: Please always keep your code formatted this will help you in many ways and safe you a lot of time!

Comment: could u clarify what u refer to when saying "formatted"? and thank you for the code, ill check it out. see if it works.

Comment: thank you very much, ur code worked and I wil l def read into that article.